# Calculating 90th percentile and group by column with date filter - PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am stuck with the below problem and need your help and inputs to solve my below problem.

I have a table with the below data. Here T1,T2,T3 are in minutes and date column also available.

[image]

Based on this table data, I wanted my output to look like this

[image]

Example : For Category Factory, I wanted to calculate the 90th percentile for T1(m) from TableA data with the fomula like = percentile.Inc([9925,20,301,45],0.90) which gives me the ouput value equals 7037.8 and for Total in the ouput also would like to calculate the 90th percentile for T1(m) equals 5638 using the same formula.

Note :- I need to have the date filter applied on the output table when i select the date range my output values should change accordingly including with my total 90th percentile values as well.

I was able to get the output for some part but my problem is I am unable to apply the date filter. Can anyone please look in to my problem and give me the samples.

Really appreciate your help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if I have simplified your problem correctly. You want a percentile measure for category. Here is sample code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bdE7DsMwDAPQu3hOAEvyd2x7jCD3v0bdBmCZgkOWB4GmlONIj7Sltj7PNvcce7Z0bhcbs4MHc4Anc9FcwcHcdHYHd+ahQ6Z80vKXnx9iNs0OvoUEmAta0SFVTzdwZe7g1ZV8wAvzBPNf89+afCu/1nz9NXQHc0MP8C27gPkoXsFc0Jt+smseYD6KTzkdWU7H2vJ8Aw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [category = _t, value = _t, date = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"value", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Add to it desired DAX measure:

```
Measure = PERCENTILE.INC(FactTable[value],0.90)
```

To filter/slice correctly the fact table on dates it is recommended to add Calendar table and set up relationship between those tables. Please check this post for further reference of Calendar tables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980662/1903793
Then build your slicer for date on Calendar table, not Fact Table.