# Custom Calendar for sales data aggregated by weeks and months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling with creating Custom Calendar that would allow me to use time intelligence function on data that is already aggregated by weeks and months. The original table with transactions contains over 20M rows, so for performance and space saving reasons the grouping is necessary and I perform it while querying the database in SQL Server. I want to create:

- Month vs Same Month Last Year
- Week vs Same Week Last Year
- Year-To-Date vs Last Year Year-To-Date (by Months)
- Year-To-Date vs Last Year Year-To-Date (by Weeks)

My idea was to assign some dummy dates to each row of data, and then create custom calendar that would have each of these dummy dates along with other details. I just cannot figure out the key (how to create dummy date having Year number Month number and Week number - please keep in mind that for example Week 5 of 2020 is  partially in January and partially in February)

Is it possible? Maybe I have to create 2 separate Calendars, one for Weeks and one for Months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add calculated table:

```
Calendar = 
GENERATE (
    CALENDAR (
        DATE ( 2016,  1,  1 ),
        DATE ( 2020, 12, 31 )
    ),
    VAR VarDates = [Date]
    VAR VarDay = DAY ( VarDates )
    VAR VarMonth =  MONTH ( VarDates )
    VAR VarYear = YEAR ( VarDates )
    VAR YM_text = FORMAT ( [Date], "yyyy-MM" )
    VAR Y_week = YEAR ( VarDates ) & "." & WEEKNUM(VarDates)

    RETURN
        ROW (
            "day"     , VarDay,
            "month"   , VarMonth,
            "year"    , VarYear,
            "YM_text" , YM_text,
            "Y_week"  , Y_week
        )
)
```

You can customize it. In relation pane connect your Date field of FactTable (which is by week, as you say. This table can have missing dates and duplicate dates, to be precise) to the field Date of the Calendar table (which has unique Date, by day). Then, in all your visuals or measures always use the the Date field of the Calendar table. It is a good practice to hide the field Date in your FactTable.

More explanations here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980662/1903793

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However,  that would be good idea, if my FactTable had Date field... As i mentioned the data is already aggregated by weeks. Which means that for one week i have only one value that represents sum of sales for whole week ( e.g.  row labeled "2019.32"  represents sales in 32-nd week of 2019 year). If i had date filled that would mean that data is aggregated by Days and achieving what i need would me much simpler. But as i also mentioned 20M rows does not load to the model in my work environment.

Comment: (1) I would modify the input data. Either do it in M (power query) by adding `Date.StartOfWeek(Date.AddWeeks(#date([Year], 1, 1), [Week]-1), Day.Monday)` or in DAX add calculated column. Transform "2019.32" to yyyy-MM-dd. (2) Alternatively try this, add in the Calendar table the field yyyy-WeekNum and connect tables in relation pane by that field.

Comment: I edited the Calendar table in my answer. You have there column Y_week. Connect it to your FactTable. However I recommend creating relation with dates, not text field, for performance reason. Obtain starting date of the week in your source data and connect it on the date to your calendar.

Comment: Smooth :)  Thank you